# What is the proper way to escape user's name in the "To" email field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

I'm sending email from my Rails 3 application:

```
mail(
    :subject => "My Subject",
    :to => "\"#{user.full_name}\" <#{user.email}>",
    ...
```

But what happens if user entered his name as `John "The Great" Doe`? Obviously, this would break my quoting of the user's name. But would the email still be delivered? Should I somehow escape the user's name when used in the "To" email field? And if yes, how: double quotes, or backslashes, etc?

Answer (score 1):

What you're really asking is how RFC2822 wants such things to be quoted. See:

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt

Note that quoting in general is a much more complicated problem than you may imagine -- quotation marks are only one of many problems you face.

That said, I would hope that Rails handles a bunch of this on your behalf -- it is commonly needed and complicated. (I am not a rails guy so I can't answer that for sure.)